# Amazon aws load balancer returns 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have created a website in nodejs framework.
After creating website i have deployed that website on amazon Elastic Beanstalk.For attaching ssl certificate i have created load balancer(http/https) and added instance to it.
After creating load balancer and adding its records in the Route 53 . website works fine.i am able to access it using domain name and load balancer link.
After few days load balancer stops working. it returns following error:

```
503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

When i open Elastic beanstalk url. it is working fine.i am able to access deployed website.
Without deploying code or making changes in Elastic Beanstalk instance after creating new load balancer site works fine.

Question :

1. How can i debug what causing issue on load balancer ?
2. How can i reslove 503 error ?